# Splunk Regex formatting

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I want to extract the field "status"="SUCCESS" from below
this value is under "textPayload"

I tried this in the regex101.com `\\"status\\":\\"(?<status>[^\"]+)` but no luck in splunk.

I want to do search on "status" message if i see "ERROR" etc. How can i extract this field.

`{"insertId":"w5xajhkklkln2ovu8z","labels":{"compute.googleapis.com/resource_name":"gke-test123-12bb9-vrl1","k8s-pod/app":"some-service","k8s-pod/environment":"dev","k8s-pod/part-of":"some-service","k8s-pod/pod-template-hash":"79mlmklcb686fcf","k8s-pod/security_istio_io/tlsMode":"istio","k8s-pod/service_istio_io/canonical-name":"some-service","k8s-pod/service_istio_io/canonical-revision":"v1","k8s-pod/stage":"dev","k8s-pod/version":"v1"},"logName":"projects/proejctname/logs/stdout","receiveTimestamp":"2022-05-30T14:00:05.27250575Z","resource":{"labels":{"cluster_name":"projectName","container_name":"some-service-v1","location":"us-east4","namespace_name":"dev","pod_name":"some-service-v1-79cb686fcf-x2frb","project_id":"proejctid-dev"},"type":"k8s_container"},"severity":"INFO","textPayload":"2022-05-30 14:00:00.590  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.a.a.controller.somecontroller : {\"classification\":\"NORMAL\",\"action\":\"ALERT\",\"host\":\"some-service-v1-79cb686fcf-x2frb\",\"ipAddr\":\"10.143.104.169\",\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"time\":\"2022-05-30T14:00:00.590Z\",\"msg\":\"getToken - Start\"}","timestamp":"2022-09-30T14:00:00.591082321Z"}`

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression is simpler, and *should* match for you:

```
<spl>
| rex field=_raw "status\W+(?<status>\w+)"
| search status="error"
<rest of spl
```

It matches the literal string `status` followed by non-word characters, then puts all found word characters into a field named `status`

Comment: Looks it worked fine. thank you. Will update if any issues.